# How to manage pull requests when forking a fork?

Tags: git, github

Consider my fork of a [github project](https://github.com/mmalmeida/xoai) (MY). it's forked from upstream (US):

> **US**  -fork--> **MY:master**

I have made some fixes in local branches (fixA and fixB), and made pull requests of those branches to US. The pull requests are still waiting to be merged in US. *I've already merged them to MY:master since I need a centralised location with all changes.*

Now another colleague (HIS) wants to help with another fix. he forks MY:master to HIS:master; creates a fix19 branch, pull requests it to MY:fix19.

> **US**  -fork--> **MY:master** --fork--> **HIS:master**

HOWEVER, when I try to pull request MY:fix19 to US:master...I notice fixA and fixB's commits are also there!

**Question:** what's the best strategy to deal with this? do I need to create *yet another* branch MY:teamDev, merge MY pull requests and HIS's pull requests there and keep MY:master completely identical to US:master (meaning it will be lagging behind until US's maintainer merges the requests ?
Should HIS have been forked out of US:master instead of MY:master? That was considered, but that also means HIS would not have access to my fixA and fixB changes - which doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: You can always point the source as your MY git repo if the US maintainer is not that active or consumed with other work until he/she finally merges your pull req.

Answer (score 0):

> HOWEVER, when I try to pull request MY:fix19 to US:master...I notice fixA and fixB's commits are also there!

Naturally, because `fixA` and `fixB` were not merged into `US:master`. So when you compare `fix19` with `US:master`, `fixA` and `fixB` will show up.

A good way to handle this is to *wait* before you create the pull request for `fix19`.

After the maintainers merged `fixA` and `fixB`, those diffs will disappear form the pull request of `fix19`.

Technically, it doesn't matter when you create the pull request for `fix19`. You can create it now, or you can create it later, the end result is the same. But it's better for the maintainers if you create it later. If you create it now, and the maintainers might look at both `fixA` and `fix19` and be dismayed to see some of the same things twice. Even more importantly, they might ask you to fix things in `fixA` first.

Logically, the maintainers should merge `fixA` and `fixB` before `fix19`. To keep things simple for them, wait with the pull request of `fix19`.

If you have other changes that don't include `fixA` and `fixB`, it's fine to create a pull request for those anytime, because the order of merging them doesn't (shouldn't) matter.

**UPDATE**

Waiting for the pending pull requests is not fun, because you have to keep track of your unmerged branches. But whose comfort is more important, yours, or the project maintainer's?

One way to keep track of the pending branches is to rename them temporarily in your repositories. You can rename them back right before creating the pull request.

If the upstream project is inactive, you can go ahead and use your fork as the main source with your team. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Tanks janos. The only problem I see with the "wait" strategy is that you might lose control over what you still need to pull request (or, worse, what happens if they reject fixA or fixB?). Would you prefer the "wait before creating the pull request" strategy as opposed to the alternative of having *yet another* branch  MY:devBranch and only merge fixes there (instead of in MY:master)?